# Using jsPDF to render an HTML string into a PDF document

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

I really need your help,

I am trying to use the jsPDF library to render an HTML string into a PDF document. When the function below is called at the click of a button it does nothing, what am I doing wrong here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.debug.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function demoLandscape() {
    var doc = new jsPDF('landscape');
    doc.text(10, 10, 'Hello landscape world!\nThis is client-side Javascript, pumping out a PDF.');

    // Save the PDF
    doc.save('Test.pdf');
}


function demoHTML() {
                var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'portrait');

                source = '<html><body><p>test HTML string</p></body></html>'

                margins = {
                    top : 80,
                    bottom : 60,
                    left : 60,
                    width : 522
                };
                // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
                // 'inches' in this case
                pdf.fromHTML(source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
                margins.left, // x coord
                margins.top, { // y coord
                    'width' : margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
                },

                function(dispose) {
                    // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
                    //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
                    pdf.save('fileNameOfGeneretedPdf.pdf');
                }, margins);
            });

        });


}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<input type="button" value="test2" onclick="demoHTML()">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: None, which is the weird part! Hence the head scratching

Comment: I have the same problem.  I moved pdf.save("test.pdf") to the last line inside the function.  It downloads...but then doesn't include additional new lines.  That is why it is in the function(dispose).  However, I am not sure why it isn't being called inside that function.

Answer (score -2):

It seems you have an extra comma in the line -

```
margins.top, { // y coord
                'width' : margins.width,
```

Try removing it?